# How to upload a file to a node.js server (using formidable) from a c# windows form using webRequest?

Tags: c#, node.js

The node server looks like this:

```
app.post('/api/upload', function(req, res){
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
    var newpath = 'C:/Users/Phili/Desktop/' + files.filetoupload.name;
    fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
      res.end();
    });
  });
});
```

I uses express for post get etc, and formidable to handle incoming file requests and file-system fs. I'm working on a c# desktop app that uses the node.js server that is hosted on an aws EC2 instance, the rest of my program works, but I cannot seem to get the upload file to work.

Can someone please help me, link me a tutorial or show me how to do it? I've handled the rest of the program in C# with Webrequests as follows, but I cannot seem to get the correct way to upload the file

```
public string sendToServer(string method, string urlEx, string[] headerKey, string[] headerVal)
{
    string URL = "http://34.253.45.82:8080" + urlEx;
    var request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    string text;
    request.Method = method;

    for (int i = 0; i < headerKey.Length; i++)
    {
        request.Headers.Add(headerKey[i], headerVal[i]);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
using (var multiPartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
     var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(image);
     fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
     {
         FileName = attachementname
     };
     multiPartContent.Add(fileContent);
     HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, multiPartContent);

     Stream body = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
     .....

}
```